# CSS in JS Dynamic apps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On this page,

[Javascript Maps Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

the code example for generating a map works fine, and I've sorted out how to pass in PHP variables.

But I am too much of a novice to grasp how to align the map (center, right, etc.) on a page or to wrap text around it.

Can someone point me to a resource for understanding these qustions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this line?

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

That is the div that you want to position. Use CSS to add margin, padding, move it to the left and right, etc.

You've got to study up on CSS and start trying things on your own, but here is something to get you started: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/